# script to calculate the dot product of a column vector

Tags: matlab

This is my code. It keeps giving an error that Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

```
function [y_out] = my_dot(x,y)
    %for finding the inner product or dot product of two arrays
    %first need to know the size

    [m_x,n_x] = size(x);
    [m_y,n_y] = size(y);
    %ensure is row or column vectors of equal length
    if(m_x ~= 1 && n_x ~=1) || (n_y ~= 1 && n_y ~= 1)
        y_out = 'Failed';
        return
    end

    %determine if x and y are column or row vectors
    %both should be column vectors
    if (m_x == 1 || m_y ==1) %they are row vectors
        y_out = 'Failed';
        return
    end

    %make sure x and y are the same size
    if n_x ~= n_y
         y_out = 'Failed';
         return
    end

    %now do the dot product
    for i = 1:m_x
        y = sum(x(i,1) * y(i,1));
        y_out = y;
    end
end
```

this is what I get

```
    >> my_dot([1;1],[2;3])
    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

    Error in my_dot (line 26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
y = sum(x(i,1) * y(i,1));
```

you are changing `y` to be a scalar. The next loop iteration you index `y(2,1)`, which now is out of bounds.

You need a new variable in the loop:

```
y_out = 0;
for i = 1:m_x
    y_out = y_out + x(i,1) * y(i,1);
end
```

But you can also compute this with a single multiplication:

```
y_out = x.' * y;
```

There are a few other bugs in your code. For example you make sure `n_x == n_y`, but it is `m_x` and `m_y` that must be equal.

To report an error situation, use the `error` function. It's more useful to receive an actual error than having a return value that does not match the expectation of the user.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB comes with pretty good implementation built in:

```
A=rand([42,1]);
B=rand([1,42]);
C=dot(A,B);
```

Comment: `B*A` is also a dot product in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's desired?